# How to save and load different types of objects?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

During coding I frequently encounter this situation:

1. I have several objects (`ConcreteType1`, `ConcreteType2`, ...) with the same base type `AbstractType`, which has abstract methods `save` and `load` . Each object can (and has to) save some specific kind of data, by overriding the `save` method.
2. I have a list of `AbstractType` objects which contains various `ConcreteTypeX` objects.
3. I walk the list and the `save` method for each object.

At this point I think it's a good OO design. (Or am I wrong?) The problems start when I want to reload the data:

Each object can load its own data, but I have to know the concrete type in advance, so I can instantiate the right `ConcreteTypeX` and call the `load` method. So the loading method has to know a great deal about the concrete types. I usually "solved" this problem by writing some kind of marker before calling `save`, which is used by the loader to determine the right `ConcreteTypeX`.

I always had/have a bad feeling about this. It feels like some kind of anti-pattern...

Are there better ways?

EDIT:
I'm sorry for the confusion, I re-wrote some of the text.
I'm aware of serialization and perhaps there is some next-to-perfect solution in Java/.NET/yourFavoriteLanguage, but I'm searching for a general solution, which might be better and more "OOP-ish" compared to my concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't simply use serialization, then I would still definitely pull the object loading logic out of the base class.  Your instinct is correct, leading you to correctly identify  a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  The base class shouldn't need to change when you change or add derived classes.

The problem is, *something* has to load the data and instantiate those objects.  This sounds like a job for the [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Is this either .NET or Java? If so, why aren't you using serialisation?

Comment: The irony is, I usually spell it with an 's', as I'm a brit!

Comment: Ah ha! So we are rubbing off on you.  When you start drinking coffee instead of tea, then we can claim victory!

Comment: LOL.  I'm American, but I accidentally set my system to English without noticing that it was British English.  :)

Comment: It's neither .NET nor Java :)
Of course serialization would get the job done, but as does my solution. But I clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways, but let's take a step back and look at it conceptually.  What are all objects doing?  Loading and Saving.  When you get the object from memory, you really don't to have to care whether it gets its information from a file, a database, or the windows registry.  You just want the object loaded.  That's important to remember because later on, your maintanence programmer will look at the LoadFromFile() method and wonder, "Why is it called that since it really doesn't load anything from a file?"

Secondly, you're running into the issue that we all run into, and it's based in dividing work.  You want a level that handles getting data from a physical source; you want a level that manipulates this data, and you want a level that displays this data.  This is the crux of [N-Tier Development](https://web.archive.org/web/20070625214219/http://csharpstruggles.blogspot.com:80/2004/08/n-tier-development.html).  I've linked to an article that [discusses your problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/net-application-architecture-the-data-access-layer/) in great detail, and details how to create a Data Access Layer to resolve your issue.  There are also numerous code projects [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170224113830/http://www.dotnetheaven.com:80/uploadfile/tavanover/ntierdevelopmentwithms102052006231650pm/ntierdevelopmentwithms1.aspx) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161028195850/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/steveclements/archive/2006/08/31/89892.aspx).

If it's Java you seek, simply substitute 'java' for .NET and search for 'Java N-Tier development'.  However, besides syntactical differences, the design structure is the same.

Comment: The method names where meant as sketches to describe my problem. Of course I use better names in real applications :) 
But thanks for the article, I will read it!